# Как реализовать карусель превью с выводом большого изображения?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Собственно нужно сделать так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь сделать таким образом:
1. Сделал разметку и вывожу превью в основное окно.
2. Подключаю owl-carousel и пытаюсь связать скрипт с выводом и каруселью.

```js
$('.item>img').click(function() {
  var src = $(this).prop('src');
  $('#big_img').html('<img src="' + src + '">');
}); //При клике по изображению из карусели, вывожу в .big_img фотографию.

$("#owl-demo-tovar").owlCarousel({
  items: 3,
  itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
  itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3],
  lazyLoad: true,
  autoPlay: false,
  mouseDrag: false,
  addClassActive: true

}); //Сам скрипт OWL-Carousel
```

```html
<div id="big_img">Вывожу сюда основное фото большого размера</div>

<div id="owl-demo-tovar">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="lazyOwl" src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="lazyOwl" src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="lazyOwl" src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы всегда был активным второй элемент (даже при прокрутке слайдов), который по центру? И чтобы он сразу же выводился в блок с большим фото. Буду очень признателен за помощь. С jQuery на "Вы", по этому прошу помощи.